# WidgetHost Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-widget

I am trying to convert a WidgetHostActivity to Fragment but i get an error when i am trying to open WidgetManager. Here is the convert i have done so far (without OnStart and OnStop)...

```
public class FragmentBlue extends Fragment implements OnLongClickListener 
{

static final String TAG = "FragmentBlue";

public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;

public static final int RESULT_CANCELED = 0;

AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager;
AppWidgetHost mAppWidgetHost;

ViewGroup mainlayout;
TextView text;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue, container, false);

    mainlayout = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvtext);
    mainlayout.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getActivity());
    mAppWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(getActivity(), R.id.APPWIDGET_HOST_ID);


    return view;
}

/**
 * Launches the menu to select the widget. The selected widget will be on
 * the result of the activity.
 */
void selectWidget() {
    text.setText(null);
    int appWidgetId = this.mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
    pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    addEmptyData(pickIntent);
    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, R.id.REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET);
}

/**
 * This avoids a bug in the com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity,
 * which is used to select widgets. This just adds empty extras to the
 * intent, avoiding the bug.
 * 
 * See more: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4272
 */
void addEmptyData(Intent pickIntent) {
    ArrayList<AppWidgetProviderInfo> customInfo = new ArrayList<AppWidgetProviderInfo>();
    pickIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_CUSTOM_INFO, customInfo);
    ArrayList<Bundle> customExtras = new ArrayList<Bundle>();
    pickIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_CUSTOM_EXTRAS, customExtras);
}

/**
 * If the user has selected an widget, the result will be in the 'data' when
 * this function is called.
 */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == R.id.REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET) {
            configureWidget(data);
        } else if (requestCode == R.id.REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET) {
            createWidget(data);
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
        int appWidgetId = data.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
        if (appWidgetId != -1) {
            mAppWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(appWidgetId);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if the widget needs any configuration. If it needs, launches the
 * configuration activity.
 */
private void configureWidget(Intent data) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    int appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
    if (appWidgetInfo.configure != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE);
        intent.setComponent(appWidgetInfo.configure);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        startActivityForResult(intent, R.id.REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET);
    } else {
        createWidget(data);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates the widget and adds to our view layout.
 */
public void createWidget(Intent data) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    int appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);

    AppWidgetHostView hostView = mAppWidgetHost.createView(getActivity(), appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
    hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
    mainlayout.addView(hostView);

    Log.i(TAG, "The widget size is: " + appWidgetInfo.minWidth + "*" + appWidgetInfo.minHeight);
}
```

I think the problem is into `startActivityForResult(pickIntent, R.id.REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET);` cause when i change `R.id.REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET` to a number (e.g. 1) WidgetManager opens and when i choose an installed widget it does nothing (just closing the window).
I hope it is understandable.

The Erros i get are:

```
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): Process: pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo, PID: 1285
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:852)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:889)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo.FragmentBlue.selectWidget(FragmentBlue.java:72)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at pl.looksok.viewpagerdemo.FragmentBlue.onLongClick(FragmentBlue.java:214)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4474)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:18401)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-08 16:41:00.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: i added the errors in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the exception is quite straightforward. You must use smaller numbers than you use when calling:

```
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, R.id.REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET);
```

Create your own int constants and use it:

```
public static final int CODE_PICK_APPWIDGET = 1;
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, CODE_PICK_APPWIDGET);
```

Comment: Thanks!!!it worked perfectly. In Activity it was working with R.id.REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET so it was hard for me to find the error.